# Unable to restart apache on centos

Tags: linux, apache

I have a centos VM and httpd -v gives me following output

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Oct 16 2014 14:48:21
```

I shut down the server by using command:
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd stop

Now when I try to start the server, I get following error:

```
Starting httpd: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for bslm-022.corp.day.com
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

What I have read online [here](http://www.servermom.org/how-to-fix-apache-could-not-reliably-determine-fqdn/290/) is that I should add ServerName localhost in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file. **But there is no directory named /etc/apache2 on my VM**.

The content of /etc/hosts file are:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

The result of $hostname command is:

```
bslm-022.corp.day.com
```

I want the apache server to run on localhost for me.

Comment: In the error look at line 3: no listening sockets available. It looks like something else could be using the port that it needs.

Line 2 about the qualified domain name is more of a notification and shouldn't cause the server to not start.

Comment: Also try running `lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"` and putting the output in your question, that might shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in your `httpd.conf` has "Listen 80" or in any of your conf files in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*`

If it does then look at `netstat` to see what's listening

```
netstat -tunlp
```